# Typeorm listeners with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

Is it possible to use TypeORM listeners with parameters?

Example:

```
@BeforeInsert()
public async doSomething(myImportantParam) {
    // using myImportantParam here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in [@BeforeInsert](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#beforeinsert) documentation, it does not allow you to add any parameters to the listener.

However, I believe you can create a constructor for your entity that takes `myImportantParam` as an argument and you can use `this.myImportantParam` to access the value within the listener.

Below here is an example code (assume `myImportantParam` is a string).

### Entity class:

```js
@Entity()
export class Post {
    constructor(myImportantParam: string) {
        this.myImportantParam = myImportantParam;
    }

    myImportantParam: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    updateDates() {
        // Now you can use `this.myImportantParam` to access your value
        foo(this.myImportantParam);
    }
    
    /*... more code here ...*/
}
```

### Service Class:

```js
export class PostService {
    async addNewPost() {
        const myImportantParam = 'This is what I need!';
        const post = new Post(myImportantParam);

        // Add any other properties the post might have
        /*... more code here ...*/

        // Insert the updated post
        await getRepository(Post).insert(post);
    }

    /*... more code here ...*/
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers  !!!

Comment: It is not a global variable. It is an instance variable which only belongs to the entity object you created. That is why we have to use `this` to access it.

Comment: This works just as I wanted, thank you very much!